# Visual studio 'Ctrl + Alt + Click' goes to implementation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I used resharper and there has been a very useful thing .

'Ctrl + click' - goes to definition

'Ctrl + Alt + click' - goes to implementation

If there are more than one implementation the list of all implementations shows up and you can choose a necessary implementation

[image]

Is there a way to make it in the visual studio 2019.

PS: I know about visual studio Ctrl + F12 .But I'm interested particularly in ctrl + alt + click

Comment: Few years late but this is answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59007746/visual-studio-ctrl-alt-click-goes-to-implementation

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), then you can enable this in the `Options -> Search And Navigation` but I don't think VS offers this out of the box.

[image]

And if you are using [JetBrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/), then you can go to `File -> Settings`, search for `implementation` and `right click on Implementation(s)` and select `Add Mouse Shortcut` and then do `Ctrl Alt Click`

[image]